# Can I vMotion between Standard and enterprise hosts?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server, vmotion

I plan on having one Enterprise host, and a few Standard licensed hosts. Will I be able to vmotion between these 2 types of servers? I know that the memory pool will be counted separately, but can't find any information on vmotion restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

As long as both hosts have the VMotion license (which Standard does), it will work just fine.